# Including path portions in xtended pattern matching operators

Tags: bash, path, pattern-matching, glob

Given the following directory structure, where all leafs are files,

```
a
├── b
│   ├── d
│   │   └── f
│   └── e
│       └── g
└── c
    ├── d
    │   └── h
    └── e
        └── i
```

the following command lists the files `f` and `h`

```
$ ls a/@(b|c)/d/.
```

but the following fails in listing `f` and `i`

```
$ ls a/@(b/d|c/e)
ls: cannot access 'a/@(b/d|c/e)': No such file or directory
```

Clearly, I cannot put slashes in the `pattern-list`. My question is one, but maybe breaking it into pieces is better:

- Why?
- Is there any intrisic reason why doing this is impossible?
- How can I obtain the same effect with a oneliner?

Comment: A pattern for extended glob cannot use `/`, hence you're getting that error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My gut is telling me that [Filename Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Filename-Expansion) can generate **filen**ames but not **path**names.

This is a case where you can use [Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) though:

```sh
ls a/{b/d,c/e}
```